# Import existing C++ makefile project into JetBrains Appcode?

Tags: c++, appcode

Ok, I'm impatient.  I'm a JetBrains PhpStorm user and cannot wait for the release of their C++ IDE.  :-)  Their Objective-C IDE, Appcode, also supports C++.  But I can't find a good way to import a fairly large C++ project into Appcode, other than clumsy copying files one at a time.

What's a good way to create a new Appcode project that will use an existing directory structure of C++ code?  It's in Git, if that makes any difference.

Comment: It's so frustrating that this is so challenging to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jetbrains CMake plugin [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/CMake+Plugin):
You must create a CMake project file instead of your makefile and then you can import your project directly there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeamCity.  Will that TeamCity plugin also work with AppCode?

Comment: @CXJ according to their website, it seems so. http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1820?pr=phpStorm